# FCM push notification to multiple devices (different users) sendMulticast vs sendToDevice in a nodeJS Google Cloud Function?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

It seems that the fcm API allows sending to multiple tokens via sendToDevice and sendMulticast.
sendToDevice is a legacy call? Should we use sendMulticast instead?

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.messaging.Messaging#sendtodevice
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.messaging.Messaging#sendmulticast

Comment: Just wanted to ask the same thing. The parameter `registrationToken` of the `sendToDevice` can also take a list of strings. Still, the documentation states for the `sendToDevice`: Sends an FCM message to a **single** device corresponding to the provided registration token.

Comment: There is nothing "legacy" about `sendToDevice`.  You can simply choose the function that best suits your needs.  You might find the results of `sendMulticast` to be more helpful when targeting multiple devices.

Comment: I was searching for the same question and found this topic. @DougStevenson, how should the chapter "Firebase Admin SDK legacy send methods" be thought of, if not as legacy functions? (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#adminSDK-legacy-send-methods) Either way, both seem quite fine to use. sendToDevice seems to offer support for sending to 1000 tokens, while sendMulticast up to 500 tokens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"sendMulticast" returns Promise for BatchResponse  whereas "sendToDevice" returns Promise for MessagingDevicesResponse

From https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#adminSDK-legacy-send-methods  regarding "sendMulticast":

> For Firebase Admin SDKs, this operation uses the sendAll() API under
> the hood, as shown in the examples. The return value is a
> BatchResponse whose responses list corresponds to the order of the
> input tokens. This is useful when you want to check which tokens
> resulted in errors.